# What happen to <div> in HTML5?

Tags: html

In HTML5, new tags have been introduced to be able to better define a page layout. Some of the tags are header,footer,section,aside,nav,article... Previously, to define these page sections, DIVs were used. So, what will happens to DIV now?

Answer (score 7):

Nothing.

It continues to exist as the generic container element for situations where there is no other element with more appropriate semantics.

Comment: Besides, it will survive as a handy tool for grouping elements together for the purposes of styling (or scripting). And most people won’t bother trying to use semantic excuses for this.